# Is there anyway to dynamically free thread-local storage in the Win32 APIs?

Tags: c++, winapi, ssl, thread-local-storage

I need to make use of thread-local storage in a cross-platform project. Under *IX I am using pthreads and can avoid memory leaks thanks to the nice destructor function pointer passed as the second argument to `pthread_key_create`, but in Windows `TlsAlloc` has no such thing. Nor can I find a general place where any function is called on thread exit (otherwise I would homebrew some list of function pointers that get called at exit).

As it stands it seems that I have basically a situation where in order to actually use thread local storage I need to allocate my own space on the heap and pass a pointer to `TlsSetValue`, but if the thread exits ... I have no way of ensuring the memory was freed (other than someone explicitly calling `TlsGetValue` and `delete`/`free`/`HeapFree`/etc at the end of the thread function.

Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: How are your threads exiting?  The normal way is to just cleanup before your threadproc returns.

Answer (score 5):

You can get yourself a nice "finalizer" to get rid of thread-specific resources, even if the thread is terminated: use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to wait on a **copy** (via `DuplicateHandle`) of the threads' handle - you ***have to*** use the cloned handle, cause registered waits can't handle handle *{no pun intended}* closing.
Use a heap allocated structure/record to hold the finalized resources, the handle waited for and the wait handle itself, cause ***the finalizer will run in the system threadpool, NOT the finalized thread*** (which will be already dead by the time). And don't forget to finalize the finalizer :)

Comment: This sounds really interesting and I've never seen this technique used before.. is there any example code that does this anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

The entry point of a DLL ([`DLLmain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583.aspx)) is called on thread exit with a reason code of `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. It is fairly straightforward to write a DLL that keeps track of functions to call on thread exit.

Alternatively, use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread) and the `boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit` function to register a function to be called on thread exit, or use `boost::thread_specific_ptr` to wrap the TLS usage entirely.